# how to check string "should not contain leading, trailing, and mutliple commas in middle"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am able to construct regex for leading and trailing.

`(^[,\s]+)|([,\s]+$)`

But I don't know to how to negate it, it should check for non-leading and non-trailing commas.

And it should not contain double or more commas (near to each other) in the middle.

```
// example - should return following values
1. "orange" - true
2. "apple, orange" - true
3. "apple,     orange" - true
4. "apple,orange" - true
5. "apple, orange," - false
6. ",orange, apple" - false
8. "orange,, apple" - false
9. "apple,,orange" - false
```

---

Any here does know how to achieve. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use this general pattern:

```regex
^[^,]+(?:\s*,\s*[^,]+)*$
```

This will match a leading term, containing no commas, followed by zero or more commas then non comma terms.

JavaScript code:

```js
var inputs = ["orange", "apple, orange", "apple,     orange", "apple,orange", "apple, orange,", ",orange, apple", "orange,, apple", "apple,,orange"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    console.log(inputs[i] + " => " + /^[^,]+(?:\s*,\s*[^,]+)*$/.test(inputs[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the string does *not* match this basic pattern:

```
^\s*,|,\s*,|,\s*$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fioUiz/1) or [JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##HcRBCoAgEADAu6/YJEjD6hpE5z4RgdQWhbTiSqf@btIc5rKP5TWcPjZPn5JwGIFhhMp679AABXsfWA1CnLsqumXm2rwmX/6bro3IUbHWsNLN5LB1dCg5UbYVUg8ipQ8)